# ¿Cómo usar geom_label con position_dodge en ggplot2 de R?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Tengo el siguiente data frame.

```
set.seed(2022)
df<-data.frame(edad=factor(rep(15:20, each=2)),
               sexo=rep(c("F","M"),6),
               valor=sample(10:20,12,T))
```

Y realizo el siguiente gráfico.

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=edad, y=valor, fill=sexo))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(1))+
  geom_label(aes(label=valor), position = position_dodge(1), show.legend = F,
             fill="white")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, por más que he considerado la posición `dodge` en el geom_label() no logro obtener que las etiquetas se separen.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que las etiquetas también estén en posición `dodge`? Conservando el relleno en blanco (`fill="white"`).

Sino considero el argumento `fill`, ahí si obtengo las etiquetas en `dodge`. Como se ve a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, debería de salir parecido a esto último, pero con el relleno en blanco de las etiquetas.

Pst: También intenté con el argumento `bg="white"`, pero sigue saliendo igual.

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo. 

Se tiene que usar la función `position_dodge2()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que estas sobrescribiendo la dimensión `fill` con lo cual pierdes el "ajuste" de `x` a la hora de posicionar las etiquetas. Puedes usar la dimensión `group`, con esto mantienes el color de las barras y el blanco en las etiquetas, y el ajuste de `x` para estás se realiza gracias a `group`:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=edad, y=valor, group=sexo, fill=sexo))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(1))+
  geom_label(aes(label=valor), 
             position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
             show.legend = F,
             fill="white")
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la documentación:

> Dodging preserves the vertical position of an geom while adjusting the
> horizontal position. position_dodge() requires the grouping variable
> to be be specified in the global or  geom_* layer. Unlike
> position_dodge(), position_dodge2() works without a grouping variable
> in a layer. position_dodge2() works with bars and rectangles, but is
> particulary useful for arranging box plots, which can have variable
> width

Confirmamos que con `position_dodge()` necesitamos `group` y con `position_dodge2()` no es necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Entiendo que al colocar fill, se pierde el ajuste, pero porque sucede lo mismo cuando considero `bg="white"`?

Comment: Entiendo, que sería lo mismo, porque se necesita `group`, no...?

Comment: Es muy raro el comportamiento usando `bg`, por empezar, no está documentado en el `geom_label()` pero ciertamente cuando lo usas, desacomoda las etiquetas. Creo que la mejor alternativa es usar `group` con `position_dodge` o directamente `position_dodge2`

Comment: Encontré la explicación: `bg` es un alias de `fill`, cuando usas `bg = "white"` es lo mismo que hacer `fill="white"`, y con esto fuerzas el fondo en blanco, pero "desmapeas" `sexo` de esta dimensión, por lo que pierdes el posicionamiento exacto del las etiquetas. Ver: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/759c63c2fd9e00ba3322c1b74b227f63c98d2e06/R/ggplot-global.R#L40

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación.